# Escape Check Point Endpoint Security Client self-protection without Windows 10 reinstall

Tags: windows-10, checkpoint-endpoint

I installed the Windows 10 April 2018 Update. After installing I got a warning that Check Point client was not compatible. At this time I had a network connection. I then uninstalled Check Point client.

After this my WiFi connection showed "No Internet, Secured" and troubleshooter shows "Windows couldn't automatically bind the IP protocol stack to the network adapter".

I think "Issues with network adapters on Windows 10 caused by Check Point Endpoint Security Client self-protection" might be what happened:
https://supportcenter.checkpoint.com/supportcenter/portal?eventSubmit_doGoviewsolutiondetails=&solutionid=sk116313

I've since then tried a lot of things.

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/49770688/115891
- https://www.killernetworking.com/driver-downloads/kb/cat/4-ethernet-and-general-troubleshooting#faq_55
- Resetting things using netsh
- Network reset in Windows
- Going back to the previous Windows version
- Installing newer Check Point client
- Uninstalling newer Check Point client
- Uninstalling Hyper-V Windows feature
- Updating network adapter drivers

Things that might matter.

- Computer is running BitLocker encrypted drives.
- It's an MSI GT62VR 6RE notebook

Can I get back to a working network connection without reinstalling Windows?

Comment: See this Microsoft Utility "Fixes Problems that prevent existing programs from being completely uninstalled or updated".........https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17588/fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed

Comment: Also see this article on how to reset the tcpip stack...https://www.geeksinphoenix.com/blog/post/2015/06/16/how-to-reset-your-network-adapter-in-windows-10.aspx

Comment: @Moab Tried both but have no software to choose in the Utility.